# android coroutines delay() sometime delays longer than specified

Tags: delay, kotlin-coroutines

noticed the delay() sometime takes longer than specified

```
        launch {
            val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
            delay(15)
            val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
            Log.d("TAG", "delayed: ${now - start}")
            doSomeThing()
        }
```

the log shows a few times the delay takes 27ms, 20ms although most of the time it is 15ms.
is that a known behavior? what is more accurate way to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

It is not just known, but universal behavior, and has nothing to do with `delay` specifically. Application code can be suspended at any time by the OS, there's GC pauses, IO interrupts etc. With `delay` you're additionally subject to the precise implementation details of the dispatcher and how precisely it schedules tasks.

The guarantee of `delay`, just as `Thread.sleep` or any other similar function, is that it will delay for *at least* the time you specify.

Comment: seems the coroutines delay() has longer time (saw some goes up to over 100 ms) than using android postDelayed(). maybe using the postDelayed() is better?

Comment: Here's the implementation of `Dispatchers.Main.delay()`: `val block = Runnable { with(continuation) { resumeUndispatched(Unit) } } handler.postDelayed(block, timeMillis.coerceAtMost(MAX_DELAY)); continuation.invokeOnCancellation { handler.removeCallbacks(block) }` So I doubt there would be a difference.